# wordpress seo ultimate meta description not displaying in page or post

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I just downloaded and activated SEO ultimate and for some reason the description tag is empty. These are pages and when I enter something, nothing populates in the code section. I looked everywhere. Here is the code I am using to get my description from SEO ultimate.

```
<meta name="description" content="?php echo get_option('description'); ?" />
```

and tried too

```
<meta name="description" content="?php bloginfo('description'); ?" />
```

Am I missing something because it only returns:

```
<meta name="description" content="" />
```

Comment: If you are using the SEO Ultimate plugin on your website, please do  deactivate it. This not only puts an intensive load on any hosting platform, it will actually slow your site down to a grinding halt for your visitors.

Comment: any other good plugin is available... need to display title and description for page and post..

Comment: Wordpress itself has `Page Meta Bar' in all pages below the description! If not add this plugin: http://wordpress.org/plugins/pagemeta/

Comment: You can use [Wordpress-Seo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wordpress-seo/) By Yoast. It is easy and powerful to help you to work in SEO.